# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I have created a maven project. The build was success. But I am getting below error while trying to do tag preparation('mvn release:prepare') in my maven project. 
I am getting this error after adding new dependency in pom as below.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
   <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.2</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please find below error.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project print-services: You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Have you installed the svn command line tool in your pc?

Answer (score 1):

Add `-SNAPSHOT` to the artifact's version number.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
   <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you #Itzik Shachar. I have added project snapshot version. Its working now. Thank you for your effort.